# jQuery Hover/Click event on same DIV (Mobile Devices)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, click, hover

I've written a simple script that displays circles over an image.

1. When you hover over a circle it expands to a tooltip.

   ```
   $('div.tooltip').live({mouseenter:function(e){
   ... animate tooltip open;
   },mouseleave:function(e){
   ... animate tooltip closed;
   }});
   ```
2. When you click on the open tooltip it displays a lightbox with more information.

   ```
   $('div.tooltip').live('click',function(e){
   ... open related lightbox
   });
   ```

Everything works as it should, except on mobile devices. When I tap the circle to open the tooltip it fires the `click` event and completely bypasses the `mouseenter/mouseexit` events.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: How exactly would a user "hover" over an element with a touchscreen device?

Comment: that's because when you **tap** the circle to open the tooltip it should fire the **click** event.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking for an alternative/workaround to make this work out without having to chop up the code too much or add plugins. In the click event(simplified code): if(mobile_device){ $('div.tooltip').trigger('mouseenter'); } else { ... do your normal desktop tasks... };  This works and will now open the tooltip on click on mobile devices, and function as normal elsewhere (open tooltip on hover). The last thing remaining is figuring out how to THEN click the tooltip on mobile devices to open the lightbox....

Comment: use an if statement and add a class to "this" on click so it works as so:

on click if(has class){do this} else (show tooltip) then (add class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the nature of touch screen devices they dont support hover events at all. The best you could do in this regard is use a jquery plugin that supports gestures and use the single-tap and double-tap events, otherwise you would need to place the tooltip somewhere else and make it visible always or have a separate button that solely activates the tip... or you could make it so the first click activates the press and then the next click activates the second function.

Comment: The best thing you can do is *do not* consider `hover` in making a website for touchscreen devices.